# Ordered RequestMapping in spring MVC

Tags: spring-mvc

I'm working on a Spring MVC project using Annotated Controller.
One thing that I'm interested in is about the order which `@RequestMapping` instruction to be processed.
For example, I want all `/green/basic/welcome` to be mapped to `GreenController.welcome()`
but `green/{treeId}/{treeName}` to be mapped to `GreenController.viewTree(treeId, treeName)`.

I guess I need to specify two `@RequestMapping` with `@RequestMapping` of `/green/basic/welcome` to be processed first, so that it won't be interpreter as a call to `GreenControllerviewTree("basic", "welcome")`.

Can you guys guide me on that?

Comment: Are you sure you can not change the url for /green/basic/welcome to something that would not clash with /green/{treeId}/{treeName} ?

Comment: I know, that should be the way. I'm just curious about how `@RequestMapping`s are processed in order.

Comment: I'm curious about this too, and haven't yet found a clear answer.  Does anyone have insight on this?

Answer (score 10):

An exact match for a `RequestMapping` will take precedence over one with a `PathVariable`. So you would have two request mappings like you pointed out. One to handle the specific url, and the variable version will catch everything else. Spring checks for direct path matches before checking for path variable matches, so order does not matter unless you have two request mappings with the same number of path variables, which may spit out an `IllegalStateException`

Check the [source of `org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMethodMapping`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/master/spring-webmvc/src/main/java/org/springframework/web/servlet/handler/AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.java) for the specifics. It is handled in `lookupHandlerMethod()`.

To determine the best match of two `RequestMapping`s that aren't exact matches, the compareTo() method of [`RequestMappingInfo`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/master/spring-webmvc/src/main/java/org/springframework/web/servlet/mvc/method/RequestMappingInfo.java) is used.

Comment: A handy implementation detail to know. Is there any public documentation (other than source) that defines this behavior for the api?