# Spring Controller URI Matching Priority

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, model-view-controller, uri

I have following two mapping in Spring Controller

```
1. @RequestMapping(value = {"/projects/{title}_{id}/home"})

and

2. @RequestMapping(value = {"/projects/{title}/home"})
```

My requirement is to give priority to first mapping but Spring is matching the second for the URL "/project/xyz-abc_20/home"

How can I solve this?

Spring version - 4.3.7.RELEASE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you make the second mapping less specific, like that :

```java
@RequestMapping(value = {"/projects/{title}**/home"})
```

the first one will have priority. I tested it and it worked.

More explanations here : https://stackoverflow.com/a/27885037/2110284