# Ambiguous URLs, one with PathVariable

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I have Spring 3.2 web app and i have controller with following request mappings:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/test/{param1}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String method1(@PathVariable(value = "param1") String param1, ..

@RequestMapping(value = "/test/login", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String method2(//..
```

Can I be sure that if someone ask for url /test/login the method2 will be invoked? Are there any factors based on which spring decides how to handle it? Does it always choose URL without PathVariable if any exists? I can't find anything in Spring doc.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Ordered RequestMapping in spring MVC](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2326912/ordered-requestmapping-in-spring-mvc)

Comment: @so00m There isnt accepted answer. And there is nice comment for answer in that question: "A handy implementation detail to know. Is there any public documentation (other than source) that defines this behavior for the api?"

Answer (score 3):

*Can i be sure that if someone ask for url `/test/login` the method2 will be invoked?* 
**Yes.**

The mappings are resolved by specificity, the relevant piece of doc is available [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/web.html#mvc-ann-requestmapping-pattern-comparison)

> A pattern with a lower count of URI variables and wild cards is
>   considered more specific. For example `/hotels/{hotel}/*` has 1 URI
>   variable and 1 wild card and is considered more specific than
>   `/hotels/{hotel}/**` which as 1 URI variable and 2 wild cards.
>
> If two patterns have the same count, the one that is longer is
>   considered more specific. For example `/foo/bar*` is longer and
>   considered more specific than `/foo/*`.
>
> When two patterns have the same count and length, the pattern with
>   fewer wild cards is considered more specific. For example
>   `/hotels/{hotel}` is more specific than `/hotels/*`.

If the two mappings match a request, a more specific will apply. Out of the two mappings, `/test/login` is more specific.

Comment: /hotels/{hotel}/{a}/{b}/{c} if i am using URL like this how can i get the value of the a,b,c ?

Comment: You simply add an argument to the handler method,  and annotate it with @PathVariable(value ="a") String aValue etc

Comment: Sorry but i have to undo this answer, it seems that it doesnt work as expected. It cause rly strange behaviour so i advice against using this kind of urls.

Comment: @jgr Could you elaborate what kind of strange behaviour did you encounter? I did some tests and it seems to work for me? tnx

Comment: @Master Slave Could you point me to the exact documentation that this behavior you mentioned is described? thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid it is not the expected answer, but as it is not specified in the documentation it should be regarded as *undefined*.

You could just try (eventually with putting "/test/logging" method first if source file), but even if it worked, you could not be sure that it will still work with another version of Spring Framework.

My advice is: if you can, avoid such ambiguous URLs, if you cannot, just have a single catchall `@RequestMapping` and forward from it *by hand*:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/test/{param1}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String method0(@PathVariable(value = "param1") String param1, ...
    ) { // union of all parameters for both method1 and method2
    String ret;
    if ("login".equals(param1)) {
        ret = method2(/* pass parameters for method 2 */ ...);
    }
    else {
        ret = method1(/* params for method1 */ param1, ...);
    }
    return ret;
}

public String method1(String param1, ..

public String method2(//..
```

That way, you have full control on what method processes what url. Not necessarily the nicest way, but it is at least robust ...